# JavaScript throw new Error doesn't work as required

Tags: javascript, try-catch, throw

This is not my actual code but a sample of what I'm trying to perform.

```html
<script>
            try {
                function x(){
                    throw new Error('msg 1!');
                }
                function y(){
                    throw new Error('msg 2!');
                }
                //x();
            
                function call(){
                   x();
                }
    
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    var btn = document.getElementById('callbtn');
                    btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
                        call();
                    });
                });
    
                //call();    
                
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        </script>
    <input type="button" id="callbtn" value="button" >
```

Now when I try to call the function in the script directly on load, it works perfectly and displays an error message without the red remark in the console. But when I try to call it on click of the button it shows red in the console stating "Uncaught Error:".

I need to display only the error message as "msg 1".

Comment: You need to add a `try/catch` block inside your event listener for that to work.

Comment: Really that boils down to understanding what asynchronous execution means... But not sure what's the best dupe target would be...

Comment: You don't need the "new Error" bit, just throw and the string will do.

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

1. The scope of try catch is not proper.
2. If you are using `new Error()` then you should use `e.message` to get the message.
3. If you want to get the value into `e` then just use `throw "message"`

```js
  function x(){
      throw new Error("MSG 1");
  }
  function y(){
      throw "MSG 2";
  }
  //x();

  function call(){
     x();
  }

  function call1(){
     y();
  }
        
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var btn = document.getElementById('callbtn');
    var btn1 = document.getElementById('callbtn1');
    btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
      try{
        call();
      }
      catch(e){
       console.log("From X...", e.message);
      }
    });
    btn1.addEventListener("click",function(){
      try{
        call1();
      }
      catch(e){
       console.log("From Y...", e);
      }
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="callbtn" value="button For X" >
<input type="button" id="callbtn1" value="button For Y" >
```